# Is it possible to allow two instances of an activity on top?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an `Activity` where i show the profile of my user. To display the profile of contacts of the user i use the exact same `Activity`.

This is the `Activity` configuration in my `mainfest.xml`

```
<activity
   android:name=".activities.ActivityProfile"
   android:label="@string/activity_profile"
   android:launchMode="standard" />
```

When i now open up a random profile of my contacts and after that open up my own profile, the current `Activity` of my contacts profile is getting replaced by the `Activity` with my own profile. Instead i would like to push another instance of the profile `Activity` on top of the contacts profile `Activity` so that when i press back from my own profile the profile of my contact would come up from the backstack.

Is it possible to allow my android app to have two equal activities on top of each other?

**EDIT**

I could not find any other `launchMode` which would provide such behaviour. There are only `standard`, `singleTop`, `singleTask`, `singleInstance`

Comment: Fragments would be more suitable in this scenario. You can have one parent activity and can launch different instance of same fragments with different arguments. Don't forget to use FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack(String)  to retain them in stack.

Comment: Sounds like a nice workaround if it is not possible to get this behaviour using activities.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible to stack instances of the same `Activity` in standard launch mode.  For example, from your base `ActivityProfile` just call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityProfile.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Once the new activity opens, you can verify that it has not replaced the first activity, as pressing the back button will return you to the previous activity.